# Mobile platforms iCal download not working

Tags: php, ios, icalendar

I've got a simple booking platform written in PHP which works fine. When used from a desktop PC (Opera, Firefox etc) it generates an iCal file which opens perfectly to add to my calendar. However, when I access the same pages from my iPhone it does nothing. I have tried it on an Android and that seems to work, adding the event to the phone's calendar, but the iPhone (using any browser) appears to refuse to recognise the iCal file.

php file:

```
<?php
$ical = $_REQUEST["ical"];
header('Content-type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=booking.ics');
echo $ical;
?>
```

What do I need to do to this to make it iPhone friendly?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252428/1427878 indicates that iOS appears to be quite picky, about which fields are required and which aren’t, and when it comes to dates & timezone information.

Comment: There are ics validators, while they are not perfect they can help flush out what is not right with the ics file.  Use each that you find as they tend to highlight different things.  Your php code is not showing anything useful that any of us could help you with.  It sounds like the contents may be the problem.